# Как задать ширину контейнера bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

В общем нужно чтобы контейнер был с произвольной шириной. Перед скачиванием бутстрапа можно настроить сетку, но не знаю как. Вот здесь настраивается http://bootstrap-3.ru/customize.php#container-sizes

Comment: ну просто не указывать ему ширину, будет произвольная...

Answer (score 1):

А я бы не спешил задавать так ширину, лучше реализовать через offset, да, возможно на 100% нужной ширины вы не получите, но зато, когда сайт будет масштабироваться не полезет никаких сюрпризов, а при задании статического размера они будут полюбому, - в доказательство посмотрите как меняется типография и другие стили при масштабировании, и да, можете перекомпилировать само количество колонок в бутстрапе, тоже поможет, но опять таки из своего опыта скажу не всегда хорошая идея на динамических проэктах.

Answer (score 0):

просто не указывать ему ширину - стереть существующие значения, будет произвольная

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос о том, как настроить, то в поля `@container-tablet`, `@container-desktop` и `@container-large-desktop` надо проставить значение `auto`. Тогда ширина контейнера будет не конкретным числом, а привычно зависеть от типа и содержимого элемента.

Но лучше продумать, какие должны быть размеры у контейнера на каждом типе устройств и прописать их в этот кастомайзер, либо устанавливать уже непосредственно в файле стилей при разработке проекта, хотя это уже не так удобно.